# Efficient way to Circular left shift of an array by n positions using only a single 1D array.

Tags: java, arrays

Given an array of n integers and a number, d, perform  left rotations on the array. example given array [1,2,3,4,5] and shifts will be always <= size of the array and asked to shift by 1 then output will be -> [2,3,4,5,1]. I have written below code which is working fine can this be further optimised as the time complexity for mine is O(n^2)

code:

public static int[] arrayLeftRotation(int[] a, int n, int k) {

```
    if (n == 1 || n == k)
        return a;
    else {
        int track = 0;
        while (track < k) {
            int start = a[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                a[i] = a[i + 1];
            }
            a[n - 1] = start;
            track++;
        }

        return a;
    }

}
```

Comment: Surely it's `O(nk)`?

Comment: yes its O(nk) as it has a outer while and inner for loop right....

Comment: I find `java.util.Collections` class is a pretty good read for that kind of things.

Comment: With a `LinkedList` would this be the most efficient, I have the feelings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a neat trick to do this in-place, in `O(n)` time:

- Reverse the whole array (i.e. between indices `0` (inclusive) and `n` (exclusive)`;
- Reverse the portion of the array between indices `0` (inclusive) and `(n-k)` (exclusive)
- Reverse the portion of the array between indices `(n-k)` (inclusive) and `n` (exclusive)

(This assumes that `0 <= k <= n`; if this is not the case, just find a different value of `k` to a value which yields the equivalent rotation according to the above, e.g. `k = k % n` if `k >= 0`)

Each of the reversal operations is `O(n)`, there are 3 of them, so it's still `O(n)` overall. It's easy to reverse an array in-place too, so there is no extra memory overhead.